# FFmpeg. Извлечение кадров по времени

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg

Я никогда до сих пор не пользовался **FFmpeg**, и только начал изучать её. В [туториале](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.html) показано как извлекать один кадр за другим. Но меня итересует максимально быстрый способ извлечения нужного кадра по времени (очень желательно **двунаправленно**). Можно ли получить что-то типа `AVFrameContext` (*я его выдумал*), т.е. без выделения памяти для самого кадра до тех пор, пока не найдётся нужный? Т.е. нужно найти по миллисекундам, что время попадает между `prev_frame` и `next_frame`, и тогда достать `cur_frame`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать (с помощью каких функций, структур и т.п.)? Большое спасибо.

Comment: Что значит нужный? Если надо просто достать кадры по времени, то вот https://stackoverflow.com/a/21422776/4711135

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, а не через консоль? Мне нужно через C API. Но спасибо, в крайнем случае, сделаю через std::system() =)

Comment: есть структура, соответствующая сжатому кадру AVPacket https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.2/structAVPacket.html

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, но там написано "This structure stores compressed data". Т.е. всё равно данные извлекаются. А мне нужно просто узнать время. Либо ещё номер кадра, это не суть. Хорошо бы пробежать по метаданным без извлечения самих данных.

Comment: Там есть метаданные: pts, dts это время, flags - тип кадра. stream_index - тип потока (видео, аудио и так далее). Если вам нужно анализировать само изображение кадра, то в любом случае надо будет его разжимать

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, т.е. получить метаданные без данных нельзя? Чисто теоретически ведь можно физически хранить информацию о каждом кадре и сами дынне кадра порознь, как делают это в файловых системах. Возможно так и есть, и если так, то должен быть более эффективный способ.

Comment: Это пространные рассуждения, какие именно данные вас интересуют?

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, время каждого кадра. Возможно считать эти кадры, но без извлечения самих данных кадра в ОЗУ. Если такое возможно... Нет так нет.

Comment: Время кадра это pts (Presentation Timestamp) оно находится в AVPacket, то есть доступно до извлечения самого кадра и никакой лишней памяти выделять не надо

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, я вкурсе, в AVPacket и в AVFrame. Но получение обоих означает загрузку данных в ОЗУ, а если видеофайл в 10 часов будет, и что, его нужно будет перебрать с самого начала по пакету?

Comment: У вас же поток данных - до разжатия это набор AVPacket - они очень маленькие по сравнению с AVFrame (в десятки раз меньше). Получаете их из потока и выбираете те, которые вам нужны (только надо это делать с какого-то ключевого кадра, иначе будет ошибка, см. AVPacket::flags), остальные отбрасываете. А как иначе? Каким образом вы получите желаемый набор кадров без самих кадров?

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, грубо говоря получить AVPacket без поля `uint8_t *data`.

Comment: Может быть вам поможет AVStream - он создается до начала передачи данных (то есть при создании соединения) https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.2/structAVStream.html

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, вот, что я нашёл на StackOverflow ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804311/reverse-video-playback-through-ffmpeg ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашёл: [FFmpeg Docs](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.1/group__lavf__decoding.html#gaa23f7619d8d4ea0857065d9979c75ac8) или [Libav Docs](https://libav.org/documentation/doxygen/master/group__lavf__decoding.html#gaa23f7619d8d4ea0857065d9979c75ac8)

```
int av_seek_frame(AVFormatContext *s,
                  int stream_index,
                  int64_t timestamp,
                  int flags)
```

> Seek to the keyframe at timestamp.

Ищет по времени [предшествующий] [ключевой] кадр внутри указанного индекса `AVStream`.

Флаги можно найти [тут](https://libav.org/documentation/doxygen/master/avformat_8h.html):

1. AVSEEK_FLAG_BACKWARD
2. AVSEEK_FLAG_BYTE
3. AVSEEK_FLAG_ANY
4. AVSEEK_FLAG_FRAME

Вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983025/how-to-read-any-frame-while-having-frame-number-using-ffmpeg-av-seek-frame) объясняется как пользоваться флагами.